# Error while retrieving account campaigns using Google Ads API in Python

Tags: python, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I've developed a Python script with the primary goal of retrieving campaigns from a specific advertising account.

To set up the required access, I established both an Administrator account and a standard account under my Google Ads umbrella. Within the Administrator account, I generated a developer token, whereas I omitted this step for the customer account, as it doesn't necessitate a developer token.

Additionally, I created an application on Google Cloud and configured OAuth credentials, along with enabling the Google Ads API service.

As a result, I have access to the application's client_id and client_secret, both stored within Google Cloud Platform. Furthermore, I possess the developer token and login customer ID from the Administrator account.

In my script, I meticulously integrated all of these credentials. I designated the login customer ID with the Administrator's advertising account ID, while I assigned the customer_id with the common advertising account ID, encapsulating all of my accounts.

Despite these preparations, upon executing the script, I encountered the following error message:

Additionally, I acquire the refresh token through the authentication process on Google OAuth Playground. Here, I input the client_id and client_secret, subsequently gaining access to the refresh token. It's worth noting that this process occurs within the same Google account where I maintain both a standard and administrator account on Google Ads.

**get_campaigns.py:**

```
import yaml
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient

with open('config.yaml', 'r') as config_file:
    config = yaml.safe_load(config_file)

try:
    client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage("config.yaml")
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"Error while configuring Google Ads client: {ex}")
    exit()

customer_id = '1161120046'  # Common Google Ads Account ID

ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")

query = (
    f"SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name FROM campaign "
    f"WHERE segments.date DURING LAST_30_DAYS"
)

try:
    response = ga_service.search(customer_id=customer_id, query=query)
    for row in response:
        print(f"Campaign ID: {row.campaign.id.value}, Name: {row.campaign.name.value}")
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"Error while fetching data: {ex}")
```

**config.yaml:**

```
developer_token: 74BVGy3feqE3GQjDTQ5lRg
login_customer_id: 7805501045

client_id: 898138229260-i0r9q8al2pq29gl8c1jgghlidgch5v54.apps.googleusercontent.com
client_secret: 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
refresh_token: 1//04v4jCWgcPj0ECgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9Irj0aXxus30cDGtMnzPjQhT3SChZdGeudMpndijtTDsf-Y7FRPmC9ezreZw_gK4Ze9WPk

use_proto_plus: True
```

**Console error:**

```
Request made: 
  ClientCustomerId: 1161120046
  Host: googleads.googleapis.com
  Method: /google.ads.googleads.v14.services.GoogleAdsService/Search
  RequestId: 8AddywJ7qvsv2Xqm4kVvsA
  IsFault: True
  FaultMessage: User doesn't have permission to access customer. Note: If you're accessing a client customer, the manager's customer id must be set in the 'login-customer-id' header. See https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/concepts/call-structure#cid

Error while fetching data: 
  (<_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
      status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
      details = "The caller does not have permission"
      debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.219.10:443 {grpc_message:"The caller does not have permission", grpc_status:7, created_time:"2023-09-29T01:26:59.3637021+00:00"}"
  >, 
  <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
      status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
      details = "The caller does not have permission"
      debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.219.10:443 {grpc_message:"The caller does not have permission", grpc_status:7, created_time:"2023-09-29T01:26:59.3637021+00:00"}"
  >, 
  errors {
    error_code {
      authorization_error: USER_PERMISSION_DENIED
    }
    message: "User doesn\'t have permission to access customer. Note: If you\'re accessing a client customer, the manager\'s customer id must be set in the \'login-customer-id\' header. See https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/concepts/call-structure#cid"
  }
  request_id: "8AddywJ7qvsv2Xqm4kVvsA"
  , '8AddywJ7qvsv2Xqm4kVvsA')
```

I'm uncertain about the cause of this error. I've supplied the credentials for the admin account, including the Developer Token and Login Customer ID. In theory, this should grant me the ability to manage campaigns within the standard ad account. However, inexplicably, the script continues to produce this error.

This is my inaugural experience with this API, and it has proven to be one of the most intricate systems I've encountered thus far. Despite devoting several days to the task, I've been unable to successfully retrieve the campaigns. I'm hopeful that someone with prior experience implementing this API can offer some guidance, as the error appears perplexing given that I've meticulously supplied the accurate credentials.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.